# How to convert List item to pdf

Tags: pdf, .net

I would like to convert list items to pdf and I was searching on internet and itextsharp came up. I read somewhere that this open source has some problems in formatting all html tags.

Does anyone know a good .net library for converting html to pdf in SharePoint? Of course it should be free.
Examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: **itextsharp** is good enough! what problem you are facing in formatting all html tags?

Comment: my colleague mentioned that he had problems with `br`tag when converting html to PDF in asp.net mvc. I have not tried it yet in SharePoint as I am gathering information first about any library that might do the job.